# Fast concurrent checking of SOA DNS records for .co.za domains

Tags: c#, asp.net, dns, soa, mx-record

I want to implement **bulk availability checking** of **.co.za** domain names as accurately as possible by checking for the existence of **SOA** or **MX records** using C# ASP.NET.

I am looking for a solution that can check for the relevant DNS records in a way that properly utilises threading to check at least 10 domains at a time.

### **"Why don't you just use an API?"**

The only truly accurate way of checking the availibility of a .co.za domain is to use http://co.za/whois.shtml, but the archaic WHOIS service does not allow bulk checking and limits consecutive checks for a given IP.

### Previous Work

To date, I have gotten *fairly* accurate results by using my ancient classic ASP script utilising an old DNS library called "Simple DNS Resolver" by Emmanuel Kartmann. However, this approach **does not scale well** and I need to be able to handle more users with a properly threaded ASP.NET implementation.

The naughty code I'm using right now looks something like this:

```
Dim oDNS, pDomain, found_names

Set oDNS = CreateObject("Emmanuel.SimpleDNSClient.1")

oDNS.ServerAddresses = "127.0.0.1" // Set DNS server to use
oDNS.Separator = "," // Set separator for found_names multiple outputs
```

Execute the following for each domain:

```
Err.Clear // Reset error flag. I know, I hate it too.

oDNS.Resolve pDomain, found_names, "C_IN", "T_SOA" // Look for SOA records for domain

If Err <> 0 Then // No SOA records could be found.
    Err.Clear // Reset error flag
    oDNS.GetEmailServers pDomain, found_names // Look for MX records
    If Err <> 0 Then // No MX records found either
        AssumeDomainIsAvailable(pDomain);
    Else // Found some MX records
        DomainUnavailable(pDomain);
    End If

Else // Found some SOA records
    DomainUnavailable(pDomain);
End If
```

Any recommendation for improving detection is appreciated. This is my first question on SO, so forgive my verbosity and thanks for your precious time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be very easy using JH Software's [DNS Client Library for .NET](http://www.simpledns.com/dns-client-lib.aspx):

```
var Response = JHSoftware.DnsClient.Lookup("example.com", 
                              JHSoftware.DnsClient.RecordType.SOA);
```

It also supports `BeginLookup` / `EndLookup` methods for asynchronous lookups.

Comment: Thanks. Simpler to implement than Gonzalo's answer, especially with Async calls. Performance will be the final verdict.

Answer (score 0):

If the service offered on the Web 
"limits consecutive checks for a given IP", it is probably for good reasons (both to preserve the system and to make life more difficult for speculators). Calling it "archaic" certainly will not help.

Also, a lot of DNS requests may be seen as a violation of the terms of service and/or as a dictionary attack and may (disclaimer: I do not know the policies of co.za) lead to blacklisting.

Comment: Not helpful at all. Compare the checking capabilities of mayor TLDs (.com) with the restrictive service available for .co.za. Ever tried to manually register a .co.za? Try the Archaic plaintext whitespace-sensitive form.